# C# starting tasks to run async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to create Tasks that will run async methods, the issue is that I cannot `await` the `Action` parameter in the Task's constructor, or the the parameters for `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Depending on how I'm instantiating my tasks, I have different issues. I have provided seven examples with comments on the issues each creates below.

**Example Code: (seven examples of task creation)**

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    private bool active = true;

    private async Task StartTasks()
    {
        int numTasks = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
        {
            //Task status is almost instantly "RanTocompletion" while work is still being done
            Task task = new Task<Task>(DoWork, "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.Start();

            //Cannot await method group
            Task task = new Task(await DoWork, "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.Start();

            //Task status is almost instantly "RanTocompletion" while work is still being done
            Task task = new Task(async (object state) => await DoWork(state), "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.Start();

            //Throws a "Start may not be called on a promise-style task." Exception
            Task task = new Task<Task>(DoWork, "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Unwrap();
            task.Start();

            //Task starts doing work after Start() is called, then throws a "Start may not be called on a promise-style task." Exception
            Task task = new Task(DoWork, "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.Start();

            //Task starts doing work, but status is "WaitingForActivation
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork, "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            //Throws a "Start may not be called on a promise-style task." Exception
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork, "someinfo", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Unwrap();

            //For checking up on tasks as work is done
            Tasks.TryAdd(task.Id, Task);
        }
    }

    private async Task DoWork(object state)
    {
        while (active)
        {
            await MakeHttpRequest();
            await DoSomethingCpuBound();
            //..etc
        }
        //do any cleanup and return
    }
```

I cannot use `Task.Run()` since that does not provide `TaskCreationOptions`. These tasks will run for literal days.

How can I start a task to await an async action?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. You're trying to solve X and you think Y is the answer, but you don't know how to do Y so you're asking about that. It would be better you ask about X instead. You should show us what the X is.

Comment: As a last resort you could create synchronous anonymous delegate for `Task.Factory.StartNew` and wait via `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm using `HttpClient` to download pages from a website I'm scraping. Since there are long delays, the more pages I can pull in parallel the better. This works, but I want to be able to see the Tasks status. When running this non-async threads get blocked while waiting on `HttpClient`. I'm trying to solve for that

Comment: @DouglasGaskell so a single page download would take days?

Comment: @zerkms 30 million of them do, yes

Comment: No, I asked about a single page download. What would be the longest per one page.

Comment: @zerkms it ranges from 200-900ms for a reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150554/discussion-between-zerkms-and-douglas-gaskell).

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - This is an X-Y problem. This sounds like a perfect job for Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx). You really should post the working code for your scraping and ask us about that.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think you may have the wrong impression of what an x-y problem is, t least in this context, this is nothing of the sort. This was a simple problem with my understanding of Tasks and how they are used, nothing more. The constant erroneous overuse/trolling of `that's an x-y problem` is turning into it's own problem here on SO. Especially when the probing results in textbook broad questions.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - You might need to explain more clearly what you're trying to do so that we don't have to reach for the X-Y problem comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sincere question. Looking at my post, what is unclear about it, what could I have changed or done better? I am trying to start a task with an async method as the target, and running into various errors. The goal is to figure out how to start a task pointed at an async method.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - An [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I start a task to await an async action?

In the TAP, [tasks are returned "hot"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#task-status). So you literally just need to call the method and keep the task it returns:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task> Tasks { get; set; }
private async Task StartTasks()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    Task task = DoWork(null);
    Tasks.TryAdd(task.Id, task);
  }
}
```

> I cannot use Task.Run() since that does not provide TaskCreationOptions. These tasks will run for literal days.

You don't need `TaskCreationOptions`. [The `LongRunning` flag is just a hint, and the thread pool will recover within a couple of seconds even if you don't specify that hint](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). But that doesn't even matter, because your work is *asynchronous* so it doesn't need to run on the thread pool in the first place.

Comment: I'm actually honored to get a response from you, was just reading your blog posts after someone linked me to them.

`The Task = DoWork(null);` is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the explanation and the link.